# Where can I find a dataset that contains criminal case sentencing data?

Tags: dataset, data, bigdata

I would like to study a dataset where each record represents a criminals case in the US and contains attributes such as:

- Type of crime
- Defendant Age/Sex/Race
- Plea
- Verdict
- Sentence

Is there a dataset like this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you checked this already, kaggle.com crime tag:

[kaggle crime tag](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets?search=crime)

Where yo have some interesting datasets, like:

[Executions in the United States, 1976-2016](https://www.kaggle.com/usdpic/execution-database)

Comment: One line and link only answers tend to get flagged for deletion.